# getting Undefined step: When method GET error while running Cucumber test although test is mapped with Kararte

Tags: karate

When method GET
    Then status 200

ERROR

Undefined step: When  method GET

Undefined step: Then  status 200

despite its getting StepDefs file of Karate.

Not able to execute the test case through Karate

Comment: I think your question is not clear at all. How are you executing the test-case ? Where are you seeing the error ? Are you using an IDE ? Which IDE ? Have you tried the "quickstart" from the documentation ? please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Its Intellij that I am using, My test case is mapped with StepDefs file of Karate but when I am running its saying undefined steps.  Something that I have to pass while running the Test Case

Comment: I am integrating with our existing Cucumber Framework..

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it is clear you are trying something which Karate does not support.

> I am integrating with our existing Cucumber Framework.

This may be possible in a future version, but please read this ticket very carefully, and if needed continue the discussion there:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/444